# How to update child iFrame's entire html (header+body) inside jQuery's post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, frameset

I have a chat webpage for Firefox that is structured like this

..... Outer HTML

-----|......Frameset Frame

------------|...... header: contains jQuery post has returned data: rdata = new_iFrame_html_str, the entire html string of the iFrame that should be updated

------------|...... iFrame

--------------------|...... header: contains jQuery

--------------------|...... body: chat messages that depends on the header jQuery to behave properly

QUESTION: I can't this jQuery post to work, i.e. I can't find a way for this post to update the *ENTIRE* iFrame (header + body).

Things I've tried and FAILED with javascript and jQuery:

1. top.frames['framesetFrame_name'].document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentDocument.body.innerHTML = new_iFrame_html_str;

   - I don't like this because it's only changing the body, not the header, so the behavior generated from jQuery can't be shown
2. top.frames['framesetFrame_name'].document.getElementById('iframe_bucinid').contentWindow.location.reload();

   - I do *not want to reload* because a reload makes the iFrame flicker, bad for a chat program
3. top.frames['framesetFrame_name'].document.getElementById('iframe_id').contents().html = new_iFrame_html_str;

   - Not updating anything that shows :(
4. top.frames['framesetFrame_name'].document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.location.href = new_iFrame_html_str;

   - This is actually the wrong form here, because it should be = url_of_new_content
5. $( top.frames['framesetFrame_name'].document.getElementById('iframe_id') ).html( new_iFrame_html_str ) ;

   - Not updating anything that shows :(

Answer (score 0):

So these two lines below are a roundabout way to get what I wanted (refresh the entire HTML of child iframe).  However, the jQuery in the head of the iframe is still not executed, even though the head is refreshed.

Does anyone know why?

The first line takes out the "" and "" since we're updating HTML's innerHTML

```
var subtxt = new_iFrame_html_str.substring(6, txt.length-9);
top.frames['framesetFrame_name']
   .frames['iframe_name']
   .document.body.parentNode.innerHTML = subtxt;
```